# Unable to delete audio file

Tags: android, mp3, delete-file

I am trying to delete an audio file in my app using the below code but for some reason it doesn't work out . file.delete() returns false even though the path is correct. Please help.I have also added WRITE and READ EXTERNAL STORAGE permission in Manifest. My phone is not connected to PC during testing.

```
    File file = new File(song.getPathId());

files.add(file);
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Confirm delete")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    for(int i=0;i<files.size();i++)
                    {

                        fileDeleted=files.get(i).delete();//returns false but path is correct
}
```

Comment: Please post an example of the path that  `getPathId()` returns.

Comment: Path id :/storage/extSdCard/Music/baby.mp3

Comment: Is file loaded in player? You can't delete file that is in use

Comment: The file is not playing when I try to delete it.

Comment: try like this `             if(files.get(i).exists()){
              if(files.get(i).canWrite()){
               fileDeleted=files.get(i).delete();
              }else{
               //file is locked...
              }
             }else{
              //file not exists
             }`

Comment: Tried your approach . File exists and file write also true but still it didn't delete the file .Feeling annoyed :(

Comment: I know that feeling :) see if this can help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)

Comment: Now tested on emulator. File is getting deleted.  But on opening the app again its throwing a runtime exception at metadataretriever set data source . The file which was deleted is still setting the path. Damn confused.

Comment: On real device not deleting still. Tested on 2 real devices.

Comment: Able to delete from internal storage path : /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/bbm_tone.wav . But unable to delete from External SD card . @jere_hr Can you suggest anything please?

Comment: I guess the issue is with Android 4.4.2 Kitkat since I am trying to delete a file which does not belong to app. Any suggestions how could it be done?

Comment: It is likely possible that this issue is only present for KitKat devices... see this: [link](http://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-sdcard-changes) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406061/howto-avoid-the-eacces-permission-denied-on-sdcard-with-kitkat-4-4-2-version)

Comment: But there should be a workaround since in other App like Samsung music player I am able to delete the file