# Unable to write a file to SD-card on android Kitkat and later but some app can still done that

Tags: android

I write/delete a file to/from SD-card root's directory, I know since Kitkat and later, Google has restricted access and don't allow to write on SD-card's root directory.
But when testing, I found that some file manager app can still write/delete file directly from SD-card of this device, example: [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm)
. I don't know how they do it. I've checked permissions of my app and File Manager app, they're the similar. Can anyone let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of how a particular app do this but there is a means to do so. See the previous answer -
[Howto avoid the "EACCES permission denied" ON SDCARD with KITKAT 4.4.2 Version. New policy from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406061/howto-avoid-the-eacces-permission-denied-on-sdcard-with-kitkat-4-4-2-version)