# saving file on sdcard with permission error

Tags: android, permissions, android-sdcard

After countless searching I've managed to find path to my sdcard not the android emulated storage. But when I try to make .txt folder there it ends up with error

```
/storage/37F0-1515/DCIM/100MEDIA/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I don't know why because I have permissions for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and also I've enabled the permissions with

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, request2);
    }
```

Here is the code that I'm using

```
    File sdCard = new File("/storage/37F0-1515/DCIM/100MEDIA");
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());


    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    final File file = new File(dir, "test" + ".txt");
    try {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        bufferedWriter.write("test");
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){Log.v("myApp", e.toString());}
```

I don't know why android won't let me write to sdcard. Do I need some other permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why because I have permissions for

Those permissions are for [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> I don't know why android won't let me write to sdcard

You do not have arbitrary filesystem access to removable storage on Android 4.4+.

Comment: So the only acces to removable storage has Google itself and the phone manufactuers... great. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: @Lowrider: No, the only *arbitrary filesystem* access to removable storage is for Google itself and device manufacturers. You are welcome to use methods like `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural) to get at *Android-supplied* locations on removable storage that you can work with using normal file I/O. Or, use [the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) to allow the user to choose where to store things, using the `Uri` you get back to open streams for reading and writing.

Answer (score -1):

Try using these methods-

1. Check if the `uses-permission` statements are in the right place, they should be below `<manifest>` and above `<application>` tags. The correct format -

   `<manifest>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
       ...
       <application>
           ...
           <activity> 
               ...
           </activity>
       </application>
   </manifest>`
2. Starting from Android Kitkat, there is a new storage policy -

> The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission must only grant write access to the primary external storage on a device. Apps must not be allowed to write to secondary external storage devices, except in their package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions. Restricting writes in this way ensures the system can clean up files when applications are uninstalled.

T<s>his can however be exploited  without rooting(although I have not tried this one), as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25872432/5210825)</s>

**EDIT -**

The above mentioned exploit won't work for Android 5+. There is no standard solution to this problem. Some exploits may be available but they will be device-specific/not reliable/root-access dependent.
However, tools like the Storage Access Framework can be used.

Comment: This technique does not work as of at least Android 5.0. This code -- once the missing pieces are filled in -- fails with an exception due to the lack of `WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE` permission. That permission is `signature|privileged`, which ordinary Android SDK apps cannot hold.